# Database mirroring with fixed set of tables without sql server replication

Tags: sql-server, replication, mirroring

We have requirement of mirroring the database with some fixed set of tables. We do not want to use sql server replication for that purpose.

Do we have any solution for that or any software for this purpose which we can use for the replication of the set of tables to remote location?

We have some set of tables around 6 to 7 that needs to be replicated in remote location so that we can have offline website setup when our live system went down. Which only shows important bit of information online for temporary purpose.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to the site. Please add as much detail into your question as possible. Questions arise such as: What's the reasoning behind this? Why don't you want to use replication? What is the connection between the servers (wan/lan?). What is the use case?

Comment: Hi Tom, We have some set of tables around 6 to 7 that needs to be replicated in remote location so that we can have offline website setup when our live system went down. Which only shows important bit of information online for temporary purpose.

Answer (score 4):

IMHO, Replication is your best choice.

Alternatively, you can look into SSIS and do an [incremental load](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Stairway+Series/76390/) to your remote database for the tables you need. If they have foreign key dependencies then make sure to load them in order.

Also, you can look into logshipping (this is entire database) and delay the restore of transaction logs, so that you can use secondary as stand by for running reports as well.

Answer (score 2):

Use Replication. It does **exactly** what you need.

Comment: Yes, But I dont want to go dipper into replication if we can replicate 5-6 tables easily

Comment: The easiest way to replicate 5-6 tables is using Replication.